# Rounded Corner Table Style for newsletter

Tags: html, css

I've got a news letter program that has a table with a border but I'm trying to make the border have rounded edges. For some reason when I add in "border-radius: 20px;" it doesn't work.

```
<table style="border-radius: 20px;  order-color: #000000; border-width: 1px; width: 680px;" border="1" cellpadding="5" rules="none" align="center">
```

I cant have a separate style sheet. It just shows a standard square border. Maybe Im doing it wrong, Im not great at html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `table` is set to `display: table;`. Change that to `display: block;` and add `border-collapse: seperate;`

example:

```
  <table style="border-radius: 20px;  border-color: #000000; border-width: 1px; width: 680px; display: block; border-collapse: separate;" border="1" cellpadding="5" rules="none" align="center">
```

**jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57we8/**

Comment: http://s8.postimage.org/w4dhc1dnp/border2.png - If you look at the screen shot, it shows the code you just gave me and the output, still shows square edges.

Comment: what browser and version are you using?

Comment: Well, Im using Dreamweaver to dev but its in all browsers. I use Chrome to test vVersion 24.0.1312.57 m

Comment: when you view outside of dream weaver how does it look?

Comment: Ooooo, yes now it looks rounded! I saved the doc and opened in Chrome. Interesting, wonder why it wont show it Dreamweaver?!

Comment: not sure, but remember to test outside of dream weaver. Use the view in dreamweaver as a kind of guide.

Comment: Definitely! Thanks! Ill make this as the answer. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
    body {
      margin: 30px;
    }
    table {
      border-collapse: separate;
      border-spacing: 0;
      min-width: 350px;
    }
    table tr th,
    table tr td {
      border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    table tr th:first-child,
    table tr td:first-child {
      border-left: 1px solid #bbb;
    }
    table tr th {
      background: #eee;
      border-top: 1px solid #bbb;
      text-align: left;
    }

    /* top-left border-radius */
    table tr:first-child th:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }

    /* top-right border-radius */
    table tr:first-child th:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }

    /* bottom-left border-radius */
    table tr:last-child td:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    }

    /* bottom-right border-radius */
    table tr:last-child td:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks! Looks great but the doc doesnt have a style sheet, its a single doc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

And then then consider including PIE.htc (http://css3pie.com/) or something similar for IE:

```
*behavior:url(PIE.htc); /* shows in IE7 and below */
_behavior:url(PIE.htc); /* shows in IE6 and below */
```

Comment: I dont have CSS thats the problem.

Comment: You can put that in the style tag that you have where you have <table style="....